# ffmpeg kit flutter IOS No such filter: 'drawtext' Error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-dependencies

I am using ffmpeg_kit_flutter and apply drawtext filter on video but i am getting errors  `No such filter: 'drawtext'`

input video link is [input.mp4](https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4)

This command it working

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex '[0]scale=540:-1[s];[s]drawtext=text='your_text_here':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2' output.mp4
```

code sample is bellow

```
/// Create Video With Text
Future<void> createVideoWithText() async {
  final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/output.mp4');
  String outPut = file.path;

  String command = "-y -i $inputFilePath -filter_complex '[0]scale=540:-1[s];[s]drawtext=text='MY_TEXT':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2' $outPut";

  FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
    command,
    (session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
print('Success full add text on video');
      }else{print('Error to adding text on video');}
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it using [the full version](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full/versions)

```
dependencies:
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full: ^5.1.0
```

instead of `ffmpeg_kit_flutter`

also, I think you don't need quote for your text :

```
drawtext=text='your_text_here'
```

=>

```
drawtext=text=your_text_here
```